# Scraping Google Finance (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape Google Finance, and get the "Related Stocks" table, which has id "cc-table" and class "gf-table" based on the webpage inspector in Chrome. (Sample Link: https://www.google.com/finance?q=tsla)

But when I run .find("table") or .findAll("table"), this table does not come up. I can find JSON-looking objects with the table's contents in the HTML content in Python, but do not know how to get it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

The page is rendered with JavaScript. There are several ways to render and scrape it.

I can scrape it with Selenium.
First install Selenium:

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

Then get a driver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

```
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver  
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = ("https://www.google.com/finance?q=tsla")
browser.get(url)
html_source = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html_source, "lxml")
for el in soup.find_all("table", {"id": "cc-table"}):
    print(el.get_text())
```

Alternatively  [PyQt5](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5)

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *  
from PyQt5.QtCore import *  
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *  
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import bs4 as bs
import sys

class Render(QWebPage):  
    def __init__(self, url):  
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
        QWebPage.__init__(self)  
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
        self.app.exec_()  

    def _loadFinished(self, result):  
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
        self.app.quit()  

url = "https://www.google.com/finance?q=tsla"
r = Render(url)  
result = r.frame.toHtml()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(result,'lxml')
for el in soup.find_all("table", {"id": "cc-table"}):
    print(el.get_text())
```

Alternatively [Dryscrape](http://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

```
import bs4 as bs
import dryscrape

url = "https://www.google.com/finance?q=tsla"
session = dryscrape.Session()
session.visit(url)
dsire_get = session.body()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(dsire_get,'lxml')
for el in soup.find_all("table", {"id": "cc-table"}):
    print(el.get_text())
```

all output:

```
Valuation▲▼Company name▲▼Price▲▼Change▲▼Chg %▲▼d | m | y▲▼Mkt Cap▲▼TSLATesla Inc328.40-1.52-0.46%53.69BDDAIFDaimler AG72.94-1.50-2.01%76.29BFFord Motor Company11.53-0.17-1.45%45.25BGMGeneral Motors Co...36.07-0.34-0.93%53.93BRNSDFRENAULT SA EUR3.8197.000.000.00%28.69BHMCHonda Motor Co Lt...27.52-0.18-0.65%49.47BAUDVFAUDI AG NPV840.400.000.00%36.14BTMToyota Motor Corp...109.31-0.53-0.48%177.79BBAMXFBAYER MOTOREN WER...94.57-2.41-2.48%56.93BNSANYNissan Motor Co L...20.400.000.00%42.85BMMTOFMITSUBISHI MOTOR ...6.86+0.091.26%10.22B
```

**EDIT**

QtWebKit got deprecated upstream in Qt 5.5 and removed in 5.6.

You can switch to PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets

Comment: could you name some of the several ways to render and scrape javascript? I thought the only way to deal with it is Selenium.

Comment: @Mohamed In my examples I have shown ways using Dryscrape, PyQt5  using QtWebKit and selenium you can use all 3 examples separately. Dryscrape is my favourite but doesn't run on windows  PyQt5 is my next favourite but I find Selenium clunky. There are 3 examples here I expect there are others checkout scrapy-splash for one example.

Comment: Can dryscrape, like requests and similar tools in python, get you banned on google for scraping? (That is without using any proxies)

Comment: I didn't get banned when I developed the script. I know google has advanced anti-robot tools. If you dont want to get banned you could try using a proxy with Selenium see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130791/how-to-enable-built-in-vpn-in-operadriver/55203283#55203283

Comment: [A new approach to installing `selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/#1-driver-management-software) is through [`webdriver-manager`](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Answer (score 2):

You can scrape Google Finance using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library without the need to use `selenium` as the data you want to extract doesn't render via Javascript. Plus it will be much faster than launching the whole browser.

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-finance-ticker-data#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, json
   
params = {
        "hl": "en" 
        }

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        }

html = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/finance?q=tsla)", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

ticker_data = []

for ticker in soup.select('.tOzDHb'):
  title = ticker.select_one('.RwFyvf').text
  price = ticker.select_one('.YMlKec').text
  index = ticker.select_one('.COaKTb').text
  price_change = ticker.select_one("[jsname=Fe7oBc]")["aria-label"]

  ticker_data.append({
    "index": index,
  "title" : title,
  "price" : price,
  "price_change" : price_change
  })  
print(json.dumps(ticker_data, indent=2))
```

Example output

```
[
  {
    "index": "Index",
    "title": "Dow Jones Industrial Average",
    "price": "32,774.41",
    "price_change": "Down by 0.18%"
  },
  {
    "index": "Index",
    "title": "S&P 500",
    "price": "4,122.47",
    "price_change": "Down by 0.42%"
  },
  {
    "index": "TSLA",
    "title": "Tesla Inc",
    "price": "$850.00",
    "price_change": "Down by 2.44%"
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

There's a [scrape Google Finance Ticker Quote Data in Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-finance-ticker-quote-data-in-python/) blog post if you need to scrape more data from Google Finance.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Probably should have gained more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Most website owners don't like scrapers because they take data the company values, use up a whole bunch of their server time and bandwidth, and give nothing in return. Big companies like Google may have entire teams employing a whole host of methods to detect and block bots trying to scrape their data.

There are several ways around this:

- Scrape from another less secured website.
- See if Google or another company has an API for public use.
- Use a more advanced scraper like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) (and probably still be blocked by google).