# how to get inner html properties of a div tag in beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

A Web site has inner HTML built in it

Beautiful soup is not extracting embeded HTML codes.

I need to extract div element with class = qwjRop

for e.g. not able to extract "At this price good" form div tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.flipkart.com/hp-pentium-quad-core-4-gb-1-tb-hdd-dos-15-be010tu-notebook/product-reviews/itmeprzhy4hs4akv?page1&pid=COMEPRZBAPXN2SNF"


def clawler(in_url):
    source_code = requests.get(in_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")    

    for name in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'qwjRop'}):
       print(name.prettify())
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the HTML you're having problems parsing?
And what exactly do you mean with "embedded HTML codes"? Do you mean an iframe?

Comment: edited the full code kindly look into it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is rendered with JavaScript you can use Selenium to render it:

First install Selenium:

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

Then get a driver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads you can use a headless version of chrome "Chrome Canary" if you are on Windows or Mac.

```
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver  
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url="https://www.flipkart.com/hp-pentium-quad-core-4-gb-1-tb-hdd-dos-15-be010tu-notebook/product-reviews/itmeprzhy4hs4akv?page1&pid=COMEPRZBAPXN2SNF"
browser.get(url)
html_source = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")
for name in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'qwjRop'}):
   print(name.prettify())
```

Or for other non-selenium methods see my answer to [Scraping Google Finance (BeautifulSoup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259232/scraping-google-finance-beautifulsoup/45259523#45259523)

Comment: Thank you, very much, scratching my head since morning to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

of course we can use Selenium as the friends said before.
Here I'd like to introduce another tools, you can use it like Scrapy, it is called scrapy_splash, a plugin of Scrapy created by the Scrapy team.
use `pip install scrapy_splash` and enjoy it, the documentation is detailed
you can write like this and the scrapy_splash will render the site for you

```
import scrapy
import scrapy_splash as scrapys
class StaticsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'statics'
    start_urls = [
    'https://stackoverflow.com/',
    ]
    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapys.SplashRequest(
                item, callback=self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5})

    def parse(self, response):
        ......
```

the response will be rendered website, you can use it in the same way if you know how to deal with response in the scrapy