# Scrape google snippet text in a certain language (English) using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to [scrape the snippet text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67278325/8192914) from google search page and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67294353/8192914) worked well. The only issue I have now is that the text is in Bangla while I want it in English.

Here's what I've tried:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('lang=en')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'the\path\for\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

I've tried adding `'lang=en'` as an argument to ChromeOptions and pass it to `webdriver.Chrome()`. That's all I could figure out but it's not working.

Here's the full code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
options.add_argument('lang=en')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\camoh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.get('https://google.com/')
assert "Google" in driver.title
#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
#wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gLFyf.gsfi")))
input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".gLFyf.gsfi")
input_field.send_keys("when barack obama born")
input_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Z0LcW.XcVN5d")))
result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".Z0LcW.XcVN5d").text
print(result)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Here's the page when I run the code:

[image: seelnium output]

Comment: I guess you have to change your language setting in chrome

Comment: @Bhavya Parikh, the language settings in my Chrome is already in English.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with below code to add argument with preferred language:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions #import library
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions() #create object of ChromeOptions 
options.add_argument("--lang=en")   
options.add_argument("--lang=en-US")#or you can use
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
```

Answer (score 1):

For scraping Google Search Answer Box no need to use `selenium` you can extract it using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library only.

For example, in the `requests` library you can pass [URL parameters](https://ahrefs.com/blog/url-parameters/#:%7E:text=URL%20parameters%20or%20query%20strings,do%20not%20change%20the%20content.) such as `hl`, `gl` or `location`  for language, country of the search and location accordingly:

```py
# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    # other parameters
    "hl": "en",                             # language, english, https://serpapi.com/google-languages
    "gl": "us",                             # country of the search, US -> USA, https://serpapi.com/google-countries
}
```

Check code in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-search-with-change-language#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": "when barack obama born",          # query example
    "hl": "en",                             # language, english, https://serpapi.com/google-languages
    "gl": "us",                             # country of the search, US -> USA, https://serpapi.com/google-countries
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

title = soup.select_one(".i29hTd").text
date = soup.select_one(".t2b5Cf").text
age = soup.select_one(".kZ91ed").text

print(title, date, age)
```

Output:

```
Barack Obama/Date of birth August 4, 1961
```

Also if you change the parameters `"hl": "en","gl": "us"` to `"hl": "de","gl": "de"` you can get the output in German:

```
Barack Obama/Geburtsdatum 4. August 1961 Alter 61 Jahre
```

---

Also you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "engine": "google",              # SerpApi search engine
  "q": "when barack obama born",   # query(answer)
  "api_key": "...",                # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key 
  "hl": "en",                      # language
  "gl": "us"                       # country of the search, US -> USA
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)      # where data extraction happens
results = search.get_dict()        # JSON -> Python dictionary
answer_box = results["answer_box"]

title = answer_box.get("title")
answer = answer_box.get("answer")

print(title, answer)
```

Output:

```
Barack Obama/Date of birth August 4, 1961
```