# Print list items in Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently extracting the following from a website using BeautifulSoup.
But am struggling to print extract the data I need.

I am looking to extract for each list entry:

The data-qty value and the href="#">4 value. So for example in the first list entry I am trying to extract href = 4 and data-qty = 1.000.

The code I am currently using is listed under the data.

```
<div class="content size-options size_us-options" data-sizegroup="size_us" style="display:none">
    <ul class="sizes small-block-grid-4">
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="24" data-price="0" data-qty="1.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="1.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-05-05" href="#">4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="172" data-price="0" data-qty="4.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="2.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-05-05" href="#">4.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="22" data-price="0" data-qty="10.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="2.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-07-05" href="#">5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="160" data-price="0" data-qty="10.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="3.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-07-05" href="#">5.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="20" data-price="0" data-qty="9.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="3.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-05-05" href="#">6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="165" data-price="0" data-qty="11.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="3.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-05-05" href="#">6.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="18" data-price="0" data-qty="28.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="3.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-05-05" href="#">7</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="110" data-price="0" data-qty="41.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="3.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-05-05" href="#">7.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="16" data-price="0" data-qty="53.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="3.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-05-05" href="#">8</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="121" data-price="0" data-qty="68.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="3.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-06-02;BBAI-0B-05-05" href="#">8.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="14" data-price="0" data-qty="85.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="4.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-07-05" href="#">9</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="114" data-price="0" data-qty="64.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="4.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-07-05" href="#">9.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="12" data-price="0" data-qty="71.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="4.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-07-05" href="#">10</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="105" data-price="0" data-qty="59.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="3.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-07-05" href="#">10.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="10" data-price="0" data-qty="61.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="3.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-07-05" href="#">11</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="117" data-price="0" data-qty="39.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="2.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-07-05" href="#">11.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="8" data-price="0" data-qty="39.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="2.0000" data-oblocators="BBAI-0B-07-05" href="#">12</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="202" data-price="0" data-qty="25.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="0.0000" data-oblocators="" href="#">12.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="nofollow" class="size-button available" data-optionIndex="126" data-price="0" data-qty="26.0000" data-qtymad="0.0000" data-qtybcn="0.0000" data-oblocators="" href="#">13</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the code that I am currently using, I am struggling to extract and print the data I need and will be thankful for any help!

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
 ukattributes = soup.find('div', {'class':'content size-options 
 size_uk-options'})
 print ukattributes
 sizes = ukattributes.findAll('li')
 print sizes
     for size in sizes:
     response = s.get(size.find('a')['href'])
     soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
     print size
```

Please let me know if you can help me with this as I have been trying for a while now! Thanks again

Comment: The HTML is not complete can we have all the source between the opening and closing div or ul elements?

Comment: @Dan-Dev I added until the closing Div thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant make a GET request on a URL # as this is not sent to the server it is probably used by JavaScript on the page or just links to the same page. See my answer to [Pagination giving the first page in every iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622383/pagination-giving-the-first-page-in-every-iteration) for more details.
So:

```
response = s.get(size.find('a')['href'])
```

Will not work as you expected. To get the data you requested try:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
ukattributes = soup.find('div', {'class':'content size-options size_us-options'})
print (ukattributes)
sizes = ukattributes.findAll('li')
print (sizes)
for size in sizes:
    href = size.find('a',href=True)
    print (href.text)
    print (href["data-qty"])
```

Outputs:

```
4
1.0000
4.5
4.0000
5
10.0000
5.5
10.0000
```

Comment: Thanks so much! @Dan-Dev this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension to select the data you need.

```
ukattributes = soup.find('div', {'class':'content size-options size_us-options'})
data = [ [a.text, a.get('data-qty')] for a in ukattributes.find_all('a') ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is really helpful in my learning for python!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that man. List comprehensions is a very handy feature.

Comment: do you know any good reads about this so that I can get more familiar?

Comment: There are many tutorials and e-books out there, but i think practice is better. You can start with someting simple like `[i for i in range(10)]` , then move to more complex structures.