# BeautifulSoup - Parsing doesn't return expected tags

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website for property sales data.
However, the parsing doesn't return what I expect. The length of `sales_containers` is simply `0`. I know, from inspecting the website, that there should be 30 divs with the class I look for.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from requests import get

url = 'http://www.boligsiden.dk/salgspris/solgt/ejerlejlighed/1?periode.from=2007-01-01&periode.to=2017-12-31&displaytab=mergedtab&sort=salgsdato&salgstype=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&by=København,%20Frederiksberg'

response = get(url)
print(response.text)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)
html_soup.prettify()

sales_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'card card-item card-item--property-sale')
print(type(sales_containers))
print(len(sales_containers))
```

I've used almost identical code on other websites, where it worked just fine.
Could it be the parser? I tried lxml with the same result.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is rendered with JavaScript. The JavaScript makes a request to another URL and the response is JSON. You can get the JSON like this:

```
from requests import get

url ="http://www.boligsiden.dk/salespriceresult/getdata?salgspristype=solgt&periode.from=2007-01-01&periode.to=2017-12-31&displaytab=mergedtab&sort=salgsdato&salgstype=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&by=K%C3%B8benhavn%2C%20Frederiksberg&boligtype=ejerlejlighed&side=1"
response = get(url)
print(response.json())
```

You can filter the result like any JSON:

```
print(response.json()['searchResult']['result']['propertySales'])
```

Alternatively you can render the page with JavaScript see my answer to [Scraping Google Finance (BeautifulSoup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259232/scraping-google-finance-beautifulsoup/) for details.