# Python Webscrape website with javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code used to work for me.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

search = 'some_website'
BeautifulSoup(urlopen(search), "lxml")
```

But now I get the following error.

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I can't do a simple request, because I need to scrape javascript information.

```
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print(soup)
```

I get the following in the soup.

```
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
```

How do I get the JavaScript off a web page when I am am getting the "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" error? Thanks for the help in advance.

I'm using python 3. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Please see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259232/scraping-google-finance-beautifulsoup/

Comment: `from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage`
This code does not work in the latest version of PyQt5. Does anyone know if they have an similar alternative to use "QWebPage"?

Answer (score 0):

QtWebKit got deprecated upstream in Qt 5.5 and removed in 5.6.

You may want to switch to PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets. 
[link](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/introduction.html#module-PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets)