# Python Requests does not return the same page if I did manually

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to submit a form, which is practically using a shipping company's website, submitting a tracking number and getting the result so that I can use beautifulsoup eventually to get the data I need. When I try this manually it returns the data, but with the python code it returns an non-formatted page and the data I need is not there as if the query was not executed. It returns

`Your Current Browser
Is Not Supported !`

which cannot be true since I am using the latest Google Chrome v.60

Where is the problem with the code?

**code:**

```
import requests
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nykline.com/ecom/CUP_HOM_3000.do?redir=Y"
payload = {'cargoTrackingNo':'TEMU9538796'}

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
with open("results.html", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)


webbrowser.open("results.html")
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You're *not* using Google Chrome, you're using `requests`. And you've commented out the line where you set the header which attempts to spoof the user-agent.

Comment: Can you submit the form in a browser with JavaScript turned off? if not it is a no JavaScript issue. or it could be a cookie issue if it works with JavaScript off

Comment: @DanielRoseman Let's forget about the `headers` line  (I deleted it from the code). I use `requests` to get  the  job done and my default browser is Chrome. You can run the code and compare it to what it is returned when doing this manually in the browser.

Comment: @DanDev I turned off the JavaScript on Chrome and the `Track` button did not work, so it did not go to the response page. How can I solve this?

Comment: see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259232/scraping-google-finance-beautifulsoup/