# Python 3: using requests does not get the full content of a web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am testing using the `requests` module to get the content of a webpage. But when I look at the content I see that it does not get the full content of the page.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://shop.nordstrom.com/c/womens-dresses-shop?origin=topnav&cm_sp=Top%20Navigation-_-Women-_-Dresses&offset=11&page=3&top=72"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Also on the chrome web-browser if I look at the page source I do not see the full content.

Is there a way to get the full content of the example page that I have provided?

Comment: "Also on the chrome web-browser if I look at the page source I do not see the full content." Why do you blame `requests` then?

Comment: The page is probably generated dynamically by javascript running in the browser.  This is very common, and there are many questions here on stackoverflow that address this exact issue.

Comment: it's probably like @larsks said , can you tell us more details, what's the missing part of code you can't see it when you show source code in browser ?

Comment: @ElisByberi I do not blame `requests`, I am just saying I am using requests.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The page is rendered with JavaScript making more requests to fetch additional data. You can fetch the complete page with selenium.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://shop.nordstrom.com/c/womens-dresses-shop?origin=topnav&cm_sp=Top%20Navigation-_-Women-_-Dresses&offset=11&page=3&top=72"
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()
print(soup.prettify())
```

For other solutions see my answer to [Scraping Google Finance (BeautifulSoup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259232/scraping-google-finance-beautifulsoup/45259523#45259523)

Comment: Thanks, when I try to run your code I get this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'

Comment: You need to download ChromeDriver and put it in your path https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: you can use a headless version of chrome "Chrome Canary" if you are on Windows.

Comment: I am on Mac, I copied the chromedriver in the same place that my python source code is but still I get error.

Comment: It's a long time since I used a Mac on Linux you put it in /usr/local/bin/ is it the same on a Mac?

Comment: There is an OSX build of Chrome canary too see https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/browser/canary.html

Comment: Thanks I noticed that I need to add the path to chromedriver in driver = webdriver.Chrome(). Now it works fine. I accepted your answer :)

Comment: I still didnt end up with any extra info added to the html file

Comment: is there any other alternative to web-driver? Web driver makes the scraping proccess slow, i want to get the data in a faster way

Comment: Google `web scraping with PyQT5`, `requests-html` (not requests) or `scrapy splash` these may be faster but rendering JavaScript takes more time than just downloading a page.

Comment: Each time I execute this snippet the browser is run. Is there a way to do this task without running the browser ?

Comment: Using Selenium you can on some operating systems run it as headless. The browser will still run but not open a window. Otherwise, you can look at using alternatives like requests-html or PyQT5. A Google search of "Selenium headless", "requests-html" or "web scraping with PyQT5" should yield results.

Answer (score -4):

Request is different from getting page source or visual elements of the web page, also viewing source from web page doesn't give you full access to everything that is on the web page including database requests and other back-end stuff. Either your question is not clear enough or you've misinterpreted how web browsing works.

Comment: this is the BSest response that I've read on stackoverflow in 2020.