# WebScraping Company Names with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull the company names from a website and have not been able to produce anything. I'm not sure if I'm selecting the wrong class or what I'm doing wrong.

Site: https://wineparis-vinexpo.com/newfront/search/exhibitors

It is the companies under the "Exhibitors" section. The first company on the list would be "0.0% Sober Spirits" and then "1884 Dumangin J. Fils" and so on.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://wineparis-vinexpo.com/newfront/search/exhibitors"
page = requests.post(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="__next")
ex_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="MuiBox-root css-k008qs")

for ex_element in ex_elements:
    company = ex_element.find("div", class_="MuiBox-root css-k008qs")
    print(company.text.strip())
    print()
```

Also, the list goes over multiply pages, but I haven't tackled that yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730671/python-3-using-requests-does-not-get-the-full-content-of-a-web-page) in essence; you need to use a web driver to get the JS to render.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://wineparis-vinexpo.com/newfront/search/exhibitors"
driver.get(url)
```

In your case, I found that I had to get the driver to progressively [scroll to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python) of the page to force the render of the list you're looking for:

```py
import time

for i in [10, 100, 1000]:
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {i});")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

then you can finally do a more honed search (note you'll need to use the `lxml` parser, not the HTML one; you'll have to `pip install lxml`):

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
results = soup.find_all("div", {"data-styleid": "product-card-title-name"})
for r in results:
    print(r.text)
```

---

So your total script will look something like:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://wineparis-vinexpo.com/newfront/search/exhibitors"
driver.get(url)

for i in [10, 100, 1000]:
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {i});")
    time.sleep(0.5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.quit()

results = soup.find_all("div", {"data-styleid": "product-card-title-name"})
for r in results:
    print(r.text)
```

I'll leave you to figure out the pagination ;)

Comment: Thank you Saul.

`code`
for i in range(1,4):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = f'https://wineparis-vinexpo.com/newfront/marketplace/exhibitors?pageNumber={i}&limit=24'.format(i)
    driver.get(url)
`code`

I used a loop for the pagination but while it briefly has the correct page in the address bar it then reverts and loads page 1. Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Check out elements like `<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiPaginationItem-root MuiPaginationItem-sizeMedium MuiPaginationItem-text MuiPaginationItem-rounded Mui-selected MuiPaginationItem-page css-gvhnql" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-current="true" aria-label="page 1">1<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span></button>`. You should be able to do something like `driver.get(<your element>).click()` and then hit the new page with the above treatment.