# Cannot extract 'pre' tag from webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I attempting to extract the all the span infomation contained in the 'pre' tag(ex. "span class="n">data") on 'https://www.kaggle.com/arthurtok/interactive-intro-to-dimensionality-reduction/notebook' using BeautifulSoup, but I can not get the information to show up. I keep getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'"

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/arthurtok/interactive-intro-to-dimensionality-reduction/notebook'
urlRead = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlRead, 'lxml')
prePrint = soup.find("pre").contents[0]
print(prePrint)
```

Am I reading the webpage incorrectly in urlRead or am I unable to extract the information using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Opening the site's source I don't find any <pre>-Tag ?!?

Comment: I am able to see the <pre> tag when inspecting the page

Comment: Is it possible that the <pre-Tag only appears on the page for logged-in users and neither I or your python script is logged in ?!?

Comment: I don't believe so, as I don't have a registered account on the site

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9sEx.jpg

Comment: `<pre>` doesn't appear in `View Source`. It does appear in `Inspect`. The `<pre>` tag isn't part of the page as downloaded, it is subsequently added by the Javascript on the page.

Comment: I agree with Rob, see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259232/scraping-google-finance-beautifulsoup/45259523#45259523 for 3 ways to scrape pages like this

Comment: Got it, thank you all!

Comment: I see three problems. The smallest: you have to use correct `USER-AGENT`. The biggest: probably script has to login to portal. Third: it keeps it in `<iframe>` which has own url https://www.kaggle.io/svf/1918919/3e1551ecf3d4fd95e467dab83112b9ec/__results__.html so server send it as separated file and you have to download it manually.

Comment: That was also very useful, thank you furas!