# Use local storage with beautiful soup

Tags: beautifulsoup, local-storage

I need to crawl a website, which stores its cookies in the users local HTML5 storage. Is there a simple way to set that using beautiful soup?

Comment: Yes there is a simple way. The page probably uses JavaScript to control the HTML5 storage so use a technology like Selenium, PyQt or Dryscrape which can handle rendering of JavaScript for examples see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259232/scraping-google-finance-beautifulsoup/45259523#45259523