# Running the Selenium Opera web driver with VPN support

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, opera

The site I try to extract data from is banned in my country.

```
Public Sub SofaScore()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "opera", "https://www.sofascore.com/table-tennis/2020-09-21"
bot.Get "/"
bot.TakeScreenshot.SaveAs (ActiveWorkbook.Path + "/Temp/screenshot.jpg")
bot.Quit
End Sub
```

This is the result I got when I ran the code without VPN support. [image]
I want to run the Selenium Opera web driver with VPN support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable built-in VPN in OperaDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130791/how-to-enable-built-in-vpn-in-operadriver)

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem unsolvable? "Running Opera browser in excel vba with VPN support"

Comment: If he solved this problem, then @QHarr would, but I guess the subject didn't interest him.